# ¿Quien me ayuda a convertir estos iconos de css a 23px?

Tags: html, css

Necesito estos iconos 23px x 23px para poder usarlos en mi página web. Ya intenté colocarlos en 23 px pero se deforman y el tamaño original es muy grande para lo que necesito. Por favor necesito que me ayuden a colocarlo en 23px Acá les dejo el código obtenido de https://codepen.io/thalseth/pen/saqIj son los primeros iconos.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Las preguntas sin código no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas como realizar una pregunta y evitar que te la cierren. Por otro lado, con solo cambiar el tamaño en esta línea `$social-icon-size: 23px;` obtienes todos los iconos en el tamaño que necesites.

Answer (score 0):

Tendras que reescribir el css de `.icon-link, .icon-link i`

```
.icon-link{
    height: 23px;
    width: 23px;
    line-height: 23px;
}
.icon-link i{
    line-height: 23px;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

Puedes seleccionar el tamaño de fuente deseado.

Answer (score 0):

Porque no usas ya una librería de iconos que contnega los que buscas?
por ejemplo, he mirado esta: [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/) y tiene todos los iconos que estas buscando.

Eso si tendrás o bien que descargarlo y hacerle referencia en el head del html de esta manera:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

O bien puedes hacer la referencia directamente a la que tienen en sus servidores:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Luego en la página que te hago refrencia buscas el icono que necesites y tan solo tendrás que copiar el código que te dan ellos, por ejemplo:

Facebook

```
<i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```